# If my webpage is blank do this

Tags: php

I have a page on my website that is fed from an RSS feed for weather alerts.  If there is an alert if will display information, if not it will be empty.  The link for this page is,

http://micklehamweather.com/rss-directbomvicalert.php

Based on a previous question I have asked here I have found out this page returns "\n" when the RSS feed is blank (rather than a blank page)

On my main page I trying to write some code to look at this page and if it is empty display one image, if not display a different image.

The code I currently have is below, but I can't seem to get it to work,

```
<?php
    if ("http://micklehamweather.com/rss-directbomvicalert.php" == "\n") {
        echo'   Alerts  <img width="20" height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;" alt="Warnings issued by the Bureau of Meteorology" src="images/alert-icon-120.png" border="0">  Warnings  <img src="/green_alert.png" width="12" height="12">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp';
    }
    else {
        echo'   Alerts  <img width="20" height="20" style="vertical-align: middle;" alt="Warnings issued by the Bureau of Meteorology" src="images/alert-icon-120.png" border="0">  Warnings  <img src="/red_alert.gif" width="12" height="12">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp';
    }
?>
```

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong or have any suggestions that would help?

I have added the code for the RSS page below

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<link type="text/css" href="rss-style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<body bgcolor="#FFE991">

<?php
    require_once("rsslib.php");
    $url = "http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDZ00055.warnings_nt.xml";
    echo RSS_Display($url, 15, false, false);
?>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Many thanks.

As per my note below. Copy of the error messages at the top of the page when the RSS feed fails,

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname in /homepages/13/d548979659/htdocs/rsslib.php on line 77

Warning: DOMDocument::load(http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDZ00059.warnings_vic.xml): failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No address associated with hostname in /homepages/13/d548979659/htdocs/rsslib.php on line 77

Comment: Try giving a space after `echo` and see?

Comment: you are comparing one string against another that doesn't match so you will always go into else.  You need to show us the code for where you read the data from the rss page

Comment: Putting an URL into a String makes it, just a string... So you are comparing a String which just so happens to be a URL, to "\n" which will never ever match, ever...

Comment: Plus your "page" as you indicated above, is a complete ( with an orphaned </fieldset> HTML Page with lots of stuff in it... So not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: sorry I am pretty new to this and I am trying to muddle my way through!  The </fieldset> should not be there, which I will remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```html
<?php
    require_once("rsslib.php");
    $url = "http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDZ00055.warnings_nt.xml";

    $rss_result = RSS_Display($url, 15, false, false); // set the result of this function to a variable rather than echoing it straight out

    echo $rss_result;  // then you can echo the variable

    // and test it:

    if (trim($rss_result) == '') // use trim too
    {
       // do green
    }
    else
    {
      // do red
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work, however if there are alerts it is showing them on the main page.  What I am trying to do is just show green image alert or red image alert only (I don't want to list the actual alerts on this page as well, which is now happening).

Comment: just remove the echo $rss_result

Comment: Can I ask one more question, sometimes the RSS feed fails and I get error messages at the top of my main page - I will add an example above.  Is there anyway to incorporate a check to say if the RSS fails then just show the green image as default?

Comment: Please can you accept this answer as it has answered this question and then ask a new question about the rss feeds failing, if you want to provide context, then link the new question to this question.  You cannot keep editing your question after it has been answered - that's not how this site works

Comment: By the looks of your errors though, they are just warnings - you may want to ask about how to surpress warnings in the php.ini